# How to filter hits by sub-aggregated results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, event-sourcing

I've been implementing an event sourcing solution backed in elasticsearch. Documents represent state change events, linked by `id` field on the _source. There's a `sequence` field starting at `0`, so that the highest sequence per `id` is the latest event for that `id`. In practice additional data will be available only on the first event and subsequent events will contain only the fields that have changed. The goal was to have an index I never have to send updates to, only inserts.

Trying to create a query that will returns the first and last events grouped by their id, if an only if their latest event's `status` matches `READY`.

Sample data:

```
[  
    {  
        "_index":"events",
        "_type":"event",
        "_id":"AWcFf2N-IqNGd75vWMgc",
        "_score":1,
        "_source":{  
            "id":"event_chain-1",
            "status":"SENT",
            "sequence":1,
            "timestamp":"1541985493824",
            "export_batch_id":"103709fe-959f-4b4e-8255-ef59f18a3cf6"
        }
    },
    {  
        "_index":"events",
        "_type":"event",
        "_id":"AWbQomwoIqNGd75vWMf6",
        "_score":1,
        "_source":{  
            "id":"event_chain-1",
            "status":"READY",
            "sequence":"0",
            "timestamp":"2018-10-31T00:00:00Z"
        }
    },
    {  
        "_index":"events",
        "_type":"event",
        "_id":"AWbQomwoIqNGd75vWabc",
        "_score":1,
        "_source":{  
            "id":"event_chain-2",
            "status":"READY",
            "sequence":"0",
            "timestamp":"2018-10-31T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

I wrote a terms aggregation on the id.keyword field, and two top_hits sub aggregations to get the first and latest events by ordering on the sequence and grabbing the top and bottom result respectively.

Problem is any matching I do on the status happens before the aggregations, and I need a way to exclude from the terms aggregation results any hits where the latest_event's status is the one that doesn't match `READY`.

What I have so far:

```
POST /events/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "status": "READY"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id.keyword",
                "order": {
                    "_term": "asc"
                },
                "size": 100
            },
            "aggs": {
                "latest_event": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "sequence": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 1
                    }
                },
                "first_event": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "sequence": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "num_ready": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "id.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would return two terms, one for `event_chain-1` and one for `event_chain-2` when I only want the one for `event_chain-2`

Terms agg `size` is so this query can be run in scheduled batches, always scraping the top of the results and updating the chains so they don't come up in the next query.

Comment: Not related to Elasticsearch, but I our apps number of events per aggregate usually is less than 100, so we just load them all and filter afterwards.

Comment: This one's write heavy, read on schedule, so our batches have to be tunable and reasonably small data-wise (which makes filtering after the query potentially hard-to-impossible since there's no garauntee you'll get any expected hits per batch if the sum of filtered and not filtered is greater than the batch size).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug deep on this and tried to look at it. I think it came down to the limitations of the individual aggregations. Can't do a sub-agg on `top_hits`, so I needed some other way to filter the results that came back.

I eventually found someone doing something similar: https://rahulsinghai.blogspot.com/2016/07/elasticsearch-pipeline-bucket-selector.html

Enter combining `top_hits`, `max` to find the `max` sequence per `id`, and `filter` aggregations at the same level, then another `max` aggregation on the `filter` aggregations to find the `max` sequence per `id` only for each result that is in status `READY`, assuming all events sharing an id have at least one event in `READY` status, then using `bucket_selector` aggregation to select the relevant set based `max` and `filter` results.

Potential Solution:

```
POST /events/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "grouped_by_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id.keyword",
                "size": 100,
                "order": {"max_seq":"desc"}
            },
            "aggs": {
                "max_seq": {"max":{"field":"sequence"}},
                "latest_event": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [{"sequence":{"order":"desc"}}],
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 1
                    }
                },
                "first_event": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [{"sequence":{"order":"asc"}}],
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 1
                    }
                },
                "filters": {
                    "filter": {"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"status":"READY"}}]}},
                    "aggs": {
                        "latest_ready_seq": {"max":{"field":"sequence"}}
                    }
                },
                "should_we_consider": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "latest_seq": "max_seq",
                            "latest_ready_seq": "filters>latest_ready_seq"
                        },
                        "script": "params.latest_seq == params.latest_ready_seq"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```